# Linux equivalent of Windows-R command (XFCE)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce

The Windows-R command in Windows 7/8/10 brings up the Run prompt where one may enter:

- A folder name (e.g. `c:\temp\docs`) and have that folder opened in the file manager (i.e. explorer).
- A command name (e.g. `putty.exe`, `notepad.exe c:\newdoc.txt`) and have that command executed if it is found in the path (or the full path may be specified).
- A document name (e.g. `d:\docs\readme.txt`) and have it opened in the associated editor.

Is there any inbuilt linux functionality or utility that can provide this unified functionality?

It basically just needs to be a window that accepts a command and if that command is a directory or non-executable file, then call `xdg-open` on it, otherwise execute the command.

The application finder is not adequate as it simply filters the setup launchers. I can't type a directory location, or `vi ~/mydoc.txt` for example.

To open a named directory, I could use the file manager shortcut, but Thunar opens without focus on the file location bar and so then requires and additional Ctrl-L. Does Thunar have any command line option to set focus to the location bar on open? The man page shows none.

I can use the open terminal shortcut to run a command (e.g. `vi ~/mydoc.txt`, `mousepad ~/the.conf`), but then I'm left with an open terminal window.

I'm hoping I've overlooked something or that there's a simple utility out there that someone might helpfully point me towards.

Comment: Alt+F2 is what it used to be on desktop Debian/Ubuntu systems, FWIR. It's been a while since I used desktop Linux though. However, this is only for Gnome, not XFCE. With XFCE you need to map a shortcut to XFRUN4 and make sure the helper program is running. See here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1773019

Comment: Alt+F2 launches the Application Finder, which is similar to the box you type in on the Windows start menu (although that one also looks at recently opened folders/docs). It simply filters launchers from the menu. This is very different functionality compared with the run command, per my description in the question.

Comment: This thread seems to indicate all you need to do is customize the commands in the application finder: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492876/xfce4-alt-f2-xfrun4-command-impotent-in-14-04-trusty with: xfce4-terminal -x bash -ic "%s ; bash"

Comment: You are correct! I had tested using home folder paths i.e. `~/` and so missed the `/` custom action mapping. Please put this down as an answer and I'll accept it. The `!` command prefix is a bit clunky, but I guess that's the cost of combining fuzzy launcher search with the run command.

Comment: Thanks. Updated, and edited and put all the back and forth into the final answer. Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with F2 in Gnome. With XFCE you can *mostly* do it, but you need to map a shortcut to xfrun4 and make sure that xfce4-settings-helper is running, then create a custom action in Application Finder. The downside here is that you need to remember to run the command with a prefix to get it to execute properly.

Set the shortcut through: Settings > Xfce 4 Settings Manager > Keyboard > Application Shortcuts.

After that's setup you need to configure a custom action within Application Finder. The following will run whatever you type in the *Run* window in bash:

```
xfce4-terminal -x bash -ic "%s ; bash"
```

For additional details see the following two threads:
Configure Shortcut: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1773019

Configure command to execute: https://askubuntu.com/questions/492876/xfce4-alt-f2-xfrun4-command-impotent-in-14-04-trusty

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth considering using a dedicated tool designed to offer standalone, powerful launching of ad-hoc commands/files. It's not necessarily necessary to use something built into a Desktop Environment.... An advantage of this is that you're not tied to a specific DE in case you decide to switch.

For example, take a look at [Interrobang](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160182), [dmenu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dmenu), or the general variety of [Application Launchers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications/Other#Application_launchers).